# Invoking methods with "fingerprints"

Tags: c#, security, plugins, methods

I want to have methods which check "fingerprints" of the invoker. For example: I got a method which modifies some values. A third-party class should not be allowed to modify value "ID", but internal classes should be allowed.

I don't want to commit the class' type so that the method could check if this class is in one of the assemblies which are allowed.
Is there the possibility that this type is automatically committed?

Or are there any alternatives for this? It's because my application allows AddIns. And those should be restricted in some actions. For this reason I need a very flexible system, which does not require much code additions or complex stuff for every method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply declare setters as internal. That will make the member accessible only to classes from your assembly.

Comment: Because with this way I must implement various overwritten methods which are just slightly modified... This doesn't reduce my amount of work spent ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are at least three options you can use.

The first and foremost, you need these values to be modifiable only from within the assembly - this is what the [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) keyword provides. If you have multiple assemblies which all need access, consider using [Friend Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx). To make the variables visible to the public but not modifiable, you can set such up like so:

```
public SomeType ID { get; internal set; }
```

Second, though it quickly becomes more complicated, you could use the above but with a protected set, and force users to go through a method-based system to modify values, allowing you to restrict, log, and otherwise do some logic during these actions. Not the easiest method.

Third would be the worst solution I can think of, and that's the use Reflection to check what's calling your setter method. This not only involves complicated code in the Get and Set properties, but could also lead to gotchas for anyone writing a plugin for your system, since they see the Setter as public even though it has extra restrictions.

Comment: For my case, the first both don't work out for me. I don't have static objects, so there's no setter which can be set to internal. It's an object that will be created more than once. It's a collection of values, and some of them should not be changed.

I just thought about a system, where I check the caller. I'm just trying this out. I know reflection is mostly the worst case. But that's the only way I can really check securely if the invoker is granted to use this method...

Comment: First, any object can have getters and setters, not just statics, if I'm understanding that first concern correctly.

Second, if it's a collection, you could implement the collection yourself (just implement IEnumerable, and have a private internal colelction you pass most functions off to) and make Add and Remove methods check for an internal boolean on the object, say IsSecure or such.

Finally, making said class use a tuple<T, bool> in it's internal collection allows you to add a permission field; make an internal Add overload for specific permission, and now you can make protected values

Comment: Hmm, sounds difficult, too... The problem is, it's no constant amount of values which should be "internal-only". It's not even specified which values (ID) should be locked for outsiders. It's completely random. But some should be locked. Setter/Getter won't work out for this ...